# Interpreting Text Files and using Strings as Variables

Tags: java

```
public void readFile()
{
    while(fileReader.hasNext())
    {
        String blankClarification1 = fileReader.next();//Why Java Why?!
        Carthage_Independent_Status = Integer.parseInt(fileReader.next());
        String blankClarification2 = fileReader.next();
        Carthage_Stability = Integer.parseInt(fileReader.next());
        String blankClarification3 = fileReader.next();
        Carthage_Ruler_Name = fileReader.next();
```

Basic text file interpretation. However it is inefficient and time consuming my question is this? is there a way to take the name of a variable from a text file and its value then make them equivalent in such a way that the variable does not have to be specifically named in the interpretation(but rather declared earlier) and the reader takes the variable name and sets it equivalent to the value next to it?

Below is the text file

```
Carthage_Independent_Status 0
Carthage_Stability 100
Carthage_Ruler_Name Dido
```

Of course there is more in it however is it possible to have something like this?

```
String Variable = fileReader.next();
String Value = fileReader.next();
Variable = Value;
```

Is there a way to program this in such a way that it sees Variable not as a string, but as a variable and thus saves time and effort? I have seen some threads regarding turning a string into a variable by mapping it, yet nothing I have tried has had the desired effect. I believe there is such a method in PHP, but then again this is Java. If any clarification of the question is needed I'll be happy to oblige I'm just naturally bad at articulating myself.

Comment: Reflection?     Really,  all I wanted to say was ' reflection? ' but that wasn't enough characters so I typed all this.

Comment: @shmosel How would this be done? I have tried it before based off this example  for the same issue                                                    Map<String, Dog> dogMap = new HashMap<String, Dog>();
dogMap.put("Fido", new Dog("Fido"));

Dog myPet = dogMap.get("Fido");                                                                  However I have not had any success can you define what dog, dogMap and Fido would represent?

Comment: @nicomp May you please give me an example of how this would be implimented? I am not exactly the most experienced at Java :/ I have seen it before in a thread, but being me was unable to use it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: is there a way to take the name of a variable from a text file and its value then make them equivalent in such a way that the variable does not have to be specifically named in the interpretation(but rather declared earlier) and the reader takes the variable name and sets it equivalent to the value next to it?`

Yes, you can use `Map<String, String>`

> Question: Is there a way to program this in such a way that it sees Variable not as a string, but as a variable and thus saves time and effort?

1.If your variables are basically primitive types or *String*, you can have some util methods. Like

```
class Configuration {
  Map<String, String> properties; // load your files into this map at first

  public String get(String key) { // if the value is string type
    return properties.get(key);
  }

  public float getFloat(String key) { // if the value is float type
    if (properties.containsKey(key)) {
      return Float.parseFloat(properties.get(key));
    } else {
      return DEFAULT_VALUE; // the default value of the key "key"
    }
  }

  public int getInt(String key) { // if the value is int type
  }
}
```

There's an in production example, take a look at [hadoop-common's Configuration.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7.2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java)

2. If you want to save variables of more complicated types into file, and read variables from file, you need serialization/deserialization toolkits. [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) would be a good start. You pre-define your Configuration class, and just save your configuration as json file, and load your Configuration class from file.